# Multiple criteria timestamp

Tags: google-sheets

I am using...

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var time = new Date(+new Date + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yyyy");
      if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(time);       
    }
}
```

...to add a timestamp+7 days to column H.

In addition to this timestamp feature... (could be another script)

1. When column D value **=** "Questions/Waiting for Info" and then **changes** to anything else.

**and**

2. When column E value = "Preliminary, Less than 25kW" **or** "Preliminary, Less than 25kW" and then **changes** to anything except for "Preliminary, Less than 25kW" **or** "Preliminary, Less than 25kW".

we want to start the timestamp+7 days over again.

It appears that this might not work with onEdit as there are some values that must be read prior to the edit. Not sure how to do this. Thanks

Correct, this is impossible using onEdit without copying the original data somewhere else first. A complicated solution out of my expertise at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this

```
function onEdit(e) {
var d = new Date(new Date() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
var time = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yyyy"),
    ind = [2, 4].indexOf(e.range.columnStart),
    off;
if (ind == 0) {
    off = 6;
} else if (ind == 1 && e.value !== "Questions/Waiting for Info") {
    off = 4;
}
e.range.offset(0, off).setValue(time)
}
```

Comment: This works when Column D is changed to anything but "Questions/Waiting for Info" and "12/31/1969" is the new timestamp. The major issue here is that I don't think an onEdit function will work. I also forgot an additional criteria and decided that the question was too vauge. See my edits above. Thanks